# How to force Python yaml.YAMLObject to dump human readable format?

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml

I want to improve YAML syntax to make human readable exchange format.

I have such code:

```
import yaml

class YamlFileLoader(yaml.Loader):
  pass

class YamlFileDumper(yaml.Dumper):
  pass

class YAMLPerson(yaml.YAMLObject):
  yaml_tag = u'!person'
  yaml_flow_style = False
  def __init__(self):
    self.first_name = u'John'
    self.last_name = u'Doe'

y = YAMLPerson()
print yaml.dump(y)
```

It produces little ugly output:

```
!person
first_name: !!python/unicode 'John'
last_name: !!python/unicode 'Doe'
```

How to transform this into nice human readable syntax like that:

```
person:
  first_name: 'John'
  last_name: 'Doe'
```

What minimal code I should add?

Answer (score 3):

Chameleon,

I reached your post through google, as I was also looking for the same. I found the answer and thought of sharing with you.

Use "default_flow_style=False", to make the output human readable. See the sample code.

```
import yaml

yaml_sample = """
  a: 1
  b:
    c: 3
    d: 4
"""

my_yaml = yaml.load(yaml_sample)

print "default style True == \n", yaml.dump(my_yaml)
print "default style False == \n", yaml.dump(my_yaml, default_flow_style=False)
```

Output,

```
default style True == 
a: 1
b: {c: 3, d: 4}

default style False == 
a: 1
b:
  c: 3
  d: 4
```